# Double.TryParse not returning proper result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double

For some reason this one particular `double.TryParse()` I have in my code is returning 0 instead of the expected result.

```
double parsedMultiplier;
double.TryParse(multiplier, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out parsedMultiplier);
```

`multiplier` is set above this code chunk and is a string. I passed it "5" and "86" (as strings) and it returns 0. I put `double.Parse(multiplier)` in Visual Studio's Watch window and it resolves the number properly. When I modified the code to read like this:

```
var parsedMultiplier = double.Parse(multiplier);
```

It returns 0 again instead of the proper number. Not sure what is going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the variable is not getting optimized out? If you print `parsedMultiplier` after, does it give you the right value?

Comment: Huh. Having it output in the console then makes it work, even though inspecting the element still shows 0 in Visual Studio. Strange bug?

Comment: No, it appears you are building in release so it may optimize out certain code. It is probably keeping the value in a register that visual studio cannot inspect, just guessing.

Comment: I am in Debug mode, so unless something is making it think it is in Release I have no idea.

Comment: I'm not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is in `multiplier` string it could have some non numeric characters like unicode 'zero wide space'
could you please check what double.TryParse returns is it true or false?
also could you post a value of `multiplier` that encoded that we could check what characters are. Please post `hexEncoded`

code:

```
string hexEncoded = string.Join("", multiplier.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X2")));
```

Comment: For some reason inspecting the code was giving me 0 but when I Console.WriteLine the variable it resolves properly. I am going to chalk this up as a strange oddity. Per your request: TryParse Result =>True; 
Hex Result => 35; Parsed Result => 5

Comment: These values looks good. So maybe it could be a debugger glitch after all. or maybe you could have a different input during that debug session